# Generate next moves of a game using python

Tags: python, logic, artificial-intelligence

I have a board 6x6 (an multidimensional array) and I want to generate the next moves for each piece, it's allowed to come back, go to vertical, horizontal and vertical positions, one square and if there's a piece n squares away in a given direction and there are n+1 empty squares after the piece in the same direction it is possible to "jump" above this piece and stop in the n+1 square.

How can I generate the tree of possible moves?
I have the following code:

```
def generate_children(depth,board,move):
tree = []
# node = board[move[2]][move[3]] 
# if(node in board): #if exists in the board
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        newboard = printBoard(board[i][j])
        if(is_allowed(newboard,move,"x")):
            tree.append(move)
print tree
return tree

def is_allowed(board,move,player):
    if((board[move[2]][move[3]] == "x") or (board[move[2]][move[3]] == "o")):
        return False
    if(board[move[0]][move[1]] == player):
        if( 
        ((move[2] == (move[0] + 1)) or (move[2] == (move[0] - 1)) or ( (move[2] == move[0]) and (move[3] != move[1]))) 
         and ((move[3] == (move[1] -1)) or (move[3] == (move[1]+1)) or( (move[3] == move[1]) and (move[2] != move[0]) ) ) ):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little more? Depending on your goal (e.g., just calculating all possible moves in this turn, calculating optimal strategy, etc.) and the type of game (e.g., turn-based, mechanics, etc.) you may need different solutions.

Comment: I need to generate all possible moves that can be done and choose the best choice in one minute, then the next player should play. The game is for 2 players and the goal is to put all the pieces on the opposite side of the board. The moves that are allowed are diagonal, horizontal and vertical, one square at a time unless that are a piece n squares away and also n+1 squares after this piece, then one can make the move , hop the piece and stop at the n+1 square (it can go in any direction). It can go backwards too.